# Can I unbrick TP Link C2 AC750 after unsuccessful installation of OpenWRT?

Tags: wireless-router, openwrt, firmware

I was trying to upgrade my router over *TFTP* to an *OpenWRT* image but I guess I used a wrong one. Now, when I turn it on, the **WAN LED flashes** for a second and **power LED stays on** all the time. No other LEDs flash, even when my computer is connected to a LAN port, the LED just doesn't light up.

The *TFTP* method doesn't work anymore as the router doesn't pull the image from my server. I tried to access serial console but had no luck - nothing appeared on the screen. So, I believe that it must be heavily corrupted. I hooked up the flash chip to my RPi 3 B+ via *SPI* and read the memory which worked fine but I'm not sure whether it's of any good use to me as it's already broken (the firmware). I tried to flash a firmware version downloaded from TP Link's website but I got an error in *flashrom* saying

> Image size (8126976 B) doesn't match the flash chip's size (8388608 B)!

Any ideas to what I should do in order to get it back on it's feet?

Comment: Is there a hard reset button on the router?

Comment: Moab - that is a good point and I have taken the liberty of adding it to my answer. Hard reset is a given in some of my router service, so I did not think to add it at the time I posted.

Comment: @Moab Yeah, that's what I used in order to "activate" _TFTP_ but when I hold it for 30 seconds and power on the router nothing happens - no _TFTP_ transfer nor router resetting to its factory defaults. I can't even access its web UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a legitimate version of firmware for the router. Download the current version and attempt to apply it.  A number of routers have a hard reset button, and if so, try that before trying the firmware.

If that does not work, the router will need to be replaced.

Most “bricked” routers must be replaced.

Comment: That's what I did and I get the message _Image size (8126976 B) doesn't match the flash chip's size (8388608 B)!_ so I was wondering whether there's something missing inside the file downloaded from TP Link's website

Comment: If you get the regular (not OpenWRT) latest firmware and it will not apply then the router looks like it cannot be fixed.

Comment: Alright, then. Now, if I bought a new router, would backing up the flash before attempting to install OpenWRT save it in case it got bricked again?

Comment: You need to make sure a new router supports OpenWRT.  Yes, set it up, and back up the entire configuration. Almost all routers let you do that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.